# Why does master not offer resources for new slave with new role?

Tags: mesos

I've a mesos cluster running with some roles, and it's working. But then I add a new server with a new role "abc" for instance. In the mesos masters I update the roles that they recognize, and restart them. I can also see in the Web UI that the slave is registered, but in the mesos master logs there's no offer for this new slave.

Does anyone knows why?

Note: I'm using mesos 0.25.0, and I'm setting the slave role by changing the property default_role

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean under "no offer for this new slave". Could you please describe your setup in more detail? A random guess: If you do not have any frameworks in role "abc", resources on the "abc" slave will be idle.

Comment: I've 3 mesos masters, and I want to launch a docker image on the cluster using marathon (setting the acceptedResourceRoles: ["spark"]). But marathon doesn't accept any resources. I also have some other services running on the mesos cluster like kafka and using slaves with the role "kafka".

Comment: I've been investigating and I found that it's because  acceptedResourceRoles it's not working in the marathon

Comment: Have you added Docker as a containerizer option? See https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html

Comment: Yup, I found this option --mesos_role which is not set